Derivative of convolution of a continuous function with a continuously differentiable function.

Suppose $f \in C^1(\mathbb R)$ has compact support and $g \in
> C(\mathbb R)$ is bounded and $\lVert g \rVert _1 < \infty$. Prove that
the convolution $f * g$ is continuously differentiable and
$\frac{d}{dx}(f*g)=(\frac{d}{dx}f)*g$.

My attempt:
Since $f$ has compact support we have $f=0$ outside $[a,b]$ for some real $a<b$. Let $x,y\in \mathbb R$. So $x-y \in [a,b] \iff y \in [x-b,x-a]$. Thus, if $x \in [a,b]$, then $y \in [a-b,b-a]$, and for all $y \notin [a-b,b-a] $ we have $f(x-y)=0$. And so from Leibniz's rule and since convolution is commutative:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}(f*g)=\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\int^{a-b}_{b-a}g(y)f(x-y)dy\Big)=\int^{a-b}_{b-a}g(y)f'(x-y)dy$$
Since $f$ vanishes thus constant outside of $[a,b]$, $f'$ also vanishes outside of $[a,b]$, and again if $y \notin [a-b,b-a]$ implies $f'(x-y)=0$. And so overall we obtain:
$$ (g*f')= \int^{a-b}_{b-a}g(y)f'(x-y)dy=\frac{d}{dx}(f*g)$$
Hence $f*g$ is differentiable. Since the convolution is continuous, $g*f'$ is continuous, thus $f*g$ is continuously differentable and $(f*g)'=f'*g$.
My only issue is that I've assumed throughout the proof that $x\in [a,b]$, and I'm not sure how to deal with the case that $x \notin [a,b]$, since I can't really see how it impacts the convolution.
